# Real time update of component in JSF 2.x Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a p:inputTextarea tied to a string value on the managed bean and the string will receive appends with a comparison of databases and I'd like to show line by line in real time.

I know ajax is capable of doing it, but considering it will be something like 10000+ lines, could it break the server or something? and can you guys link me to a question with examples of how to do it with ajax?

Comment: It would be nice to know, when those appendages happen. Otherwise this sounds like `p:poll` seems to be what you're looking for to poll for changes and propagate them to the ui via ajax.

Comment: thanks zhedar, did not know about this component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use PrimeFaces poll component. Poll component makes ajax calls in a specified interval.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml